# How to get rid of extra escape characters while doing json transformation using scala play framework?

Tags: scala, play-json

I want to update some of the fields present in a json string and I am using play framework in scala.But when I am updating the json few escape string characters are getting introduced.And I dont want these charcters after the json transformation.below are some code samples.

```
val jsonStringAsJsValue = Json.toJson("""{"counter_holders": {"Peter": 25}}""")
//play.api.libs.json.JsValue = "{\"counter_holders\": {\"Peter\": 25}}"

val jsonTransformer = (__ \"counter_holders" ).json.put(Json.toJson("""{"*****":25}"""))
//JsObject

jsonStringAsJsValue .transform(jsonTransformer).get.as[JsValue]
//Now getting the below string
//{"counter_holders":"{\"*****\":25}"}
//But I need this string
//{"counter_holders":"{"*****":25}"}
```

Either I convert resulting value to JSvalue or JSString escape charcters are getting introduced.Any help on this will be really nice.

Comment: AFAIK escaping of quotation marks in JSON string values is required by JSON specification: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8259#page-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Json.toJson` is for converting a string to a json value -- a json encoded string. You don't want that, you want to parse the strings as json. For that, use `Json.parse`

You'll end up with

```
val jsonStringAsJsValue = Json.parse("""{"counter_holders": {"Peter": 25}}""")
val jsonTransformer = (__ \"counter_holders" ).json.put(Json.parse("""{"*****":25}"""))
jsonStringAsJsValue.transform(jsonTransformer).get.as[JsValue]
```